# Reducing the filament voltage has no effect on the maximum photon energy produced by characteristic or Bremsstrahlung radiation. TRUE - why?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, photoelectric-effect, x-rays

I'm studying for my radiology exams and I don't understand the answer to this question.

It states that the following sentence is true:

> Reducing the filament voltage has no effect on the maximum photon energy produced by characteristic or Bremsstrahlung radiation.

I get that the filament voltage won't affect characteristic radiation because that is based on the target material but I don't understand how the filament voltage won't affect the maximum photo energy of Bremsstrahlung radiation.  I thought that the kVp was the only thing that changed the maximum photo energy and that is related to filament voltage, or am I getting confused?

Comment: For the outsider: “kVp” is the peak voltage across the x-ray tube, measured in kilovolts. For the asker: the first image at [this link](https://oncologymedicalphysics.com/kilovoltage-x-ray-generation/) suggests you are correct, that the maximum bremsstrahlung energy is for a single photon to carry away the electron’s entire kinetic energy, and that this bremsstrahlung endpoint is therefore equal to the peak voltage across the filament. I’ll hold off on a proper answer in case a real expert comes along.

Answer (score 1):

The filament voltage controls the filament temperature, which controls the electron current, but not the electron energy. Thus, increasing the filament voltage increases the flux of x-ray photons, but not their energy. The Bremsstrahlung cutoff remains the same.

The anode voltage controls the electron energy, and that controls the Bremsstrahlung cutoff.

Comment: Thanks for this, this makes more sense now.